# Unable to close questions

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, mobile-web, google-chrome, android

I can't close questions on mobile right now.

The page just jumps to the top and nothing else happens.

(And what kind of quality standards are preventing me from asking this question?)

Comment: I just closed this from my android phone... Can you be more specific about the scenario where it breaks?

Comment: @Shog9 I can't close or flag, neither on Safari nor Chrome for iOS (latest). Same behavior as Oliver describes. The page just scrolls to the top (to an empty `#` fragment target).

Comment: Reproduced; I wasn't using the mobile theme on meta for some reason.